# Time complexity of range(n) function in Python3

Tags: python, time-complexity

Imagine this code:

```
def code(n): 
    a = range(n) 
    b = list(a) 
    return b
```

Am I correct to say that:

- `range(n)` takes O(1) time (calling `range` in Python is constant time, right?)
- `list(a)` takes O(n) time, and
- The `return` statement takes O(1) time?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Also, just post normal code in the future, please

Comment: yes, you are...

Answer (score 3):

This is correct in Python 3; the `range` function returns a lazy iterable.

However, if you are using Python 2 then `range(n)` is also an O(n) operation, because it creates a list. `range(n)` in Python 2 is equivalent to `list(range(n))` in Python 3.

The `return` statement takes O(1) time, because it only returns a reference to the list, not a copy of it.

Comment: In Python 2, `list(range(n))` should be a no-op, or not?

Comment: No; in Python 2 `range(n)` creates a list and then `list(...)` still makes a copy of it, so two lists are created (and the first one is garbage-collected). In theory `list` could be optimized so that if the argument is a list and its refcount is 1, then it can just return the argument directly; but I don't think that optimization is actually performed.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa almost never will you see that sort of optimization in CPython (maybe in something like PyPy). The best you can expect are things like constant folding, and sometimes, caching of objects that are used as literals in code and replacing them with immutable equivalents in the bytecode, e.g. `bad_word = word in {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}` then the CPython compiler will make that a frozen set that is constructed once at compile time, but you really shouldn't rely on that, it is an implementation detail, and in any case, it is not a good practice from a clean code prespective